# Rails 3: Unit tests fail to run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to set up my unit tests for my application but any time i try run any of my unit tests i get the follwoing error when i run the test in rubymine:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'cms2_test.user_sessions' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `user_sessions`
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
Test suite finished: 0.016993 seconds
```

and here is the error i get when i try run the test in the console:

```
ruby unit/user_test.rb
/Users/aldeirm2/Desktop/CMS2/config/boot.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /Users/aldeirm2/Desktop/CMS2/config/boot.rb:1
    from /Users/aldeirm2/Desktop/CMS2/config/application.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/aldeirm2/Desktop/CMS2/config/application.rb:1
    from /Users/aldeirm2/Desktop/CMS2/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/aldeirm2/Desktop/CMS2/config/environment.rb:2
    from ./test_helper.rb:2:in `require'
    from ./test_helper.rb:2
    from unit/user_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from unit
```

/user_test.rb:1

two diffrent errors!

ANy ideas who i can get my unit tests working?

Thanks

p.s I am using authlogic for authentcation not that i think it has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have trouble running unit tests directly unless you've set up your environment to support it as sometimes the Ruby interpreter has trouble resolving the location of `test_helper`. The most reliable way of running them is `rake test:units` and you can see the command-line constructed to execute that.

The first error may be related to having a fixture file without an associated table in the schema, which in this case implies you may have `test/fixtures/user_sessions.yml` but no `user_sessions` table defined in `db/schema.rb`. Fixtures are loaded in for each test and the first step is to delete all the old records.

Comment: You are on to something, it was the fixtures problem! i dont have a user_sessions table in the database. I know its not in the scope of the question but if you have a little bit of time and dont mind can you please include a little bit of information on fixtures and how they affect the tests and what they are there for? It would help me and possibly more people with the same problem understand what was going on better. Thanks

Comment: Any `.yml` file in the fixtures directory is loaded into the associated table during the start of a unit test, but if the table is missing you get this peculiar error. Rails really should check to see if the table is present and produce a warning instead about an invalid fixture. The fixtures are used to populate your test database with any pre-defined records you might require so you don't have to create them repeatedly during your testing.

Answer (score 2):

The `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` record seems like an outdated test database. Unless you are running a full `rake` rather than running an individual spec, you need to run `rake db:test:prepare` in order to update your database tables in your testing environment. That is basically just going to match the development database schema.

When running `rake` you don't need to do so, it automatically does this for you before it starts running individual tests.

Comment: I already ran the ``rake db:test:prepare`` call, and its still giving the same error. i even tried changing the ``database.yml`` to allow tests to use the development database and it gives me the same error.